# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON property 'name' closes the circle

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms in Angular 8 to insert data into the database, but I am getting this error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. It is saying that `name` property is a circular structure and I am unable to find out why. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

**my component.ts**

```js
export class AddMainCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
    nm;
    desc;
    date;

    get name() {
        return this.addMCform.get('name')
    }

    get description() {
        return this.addMCform.get('description')
    }
    constructor(public mainCategoryService: MainCategoryService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    addMCform = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        description: ['']
    })

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    addMain_categories() {
        let main_category = {
            nm: this.name,
            desc: this.description,
            date: new Date(),

        }
        this.mainCategoryService.addMain_categories(main_category).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
}
```

**html**

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Add main category</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="addMCform">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name of main category</label>
            <input [class.is-invalid]="name.invalid && name.touched" formControlName="name" type="text"
                class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name of category">
            <div *ngIf="name.invalid && name.touched">
                <small *ngIf="name.errors?.required" class="text-danger"> name is required</small>
                <small *ngIf="name.errors?.minlength" class="text-danger"> name must be at least 3 characters </small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Description:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" input type="textarea" formControlName="description"
                placeholder="Enter description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addMain_categories()">Add main category</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this.name` returns `this.addMCform.get('name')` which is a form control. Same goes for `this.description`. In `main_category`, you need to pass the `value` and not the form control as a whole.

```js
let main_category = {
    nm: this.name.value,
    desc: this.description.value,
    date: new Date()
};
```

Comment: you are  correct , my answer show just another why by get the value from the form itself 

Comment: @malbarwami - Thanks :) I like the destructuring method you've showed as well. Pratik - That is an API error. What is your backend code written in? Check how your API is expecting the the request.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use `addMCform` value property to get the form value

```js
const {name:mn , description : desc} = this.addMCform .value

let main_category = {
      nm,
      desc, 
      date : new Date(),
};
```